# Create binary file in python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I have a very large binary file called file1.bin and I want to create a file, file2.bin, that holds only the first 32kb of file1.bin.

So I'm reading file1 as follows:

```
myArr = bytearray()

with open(r"C:\Users\User\file1.bin", "rb") as f:
byte = f.read(1)
for i in range(32,678):
    myArr.extend(byte)
    byte = f.read(1)
```

My question is: How do I proceed from here to create the file2 binary file out of myArr?

I tried

```
with open(r"C:\Users\User\file2.bin", "w") as f:
f.write(myArr)
```

but this results in:

```
f.write(myArr)
TypeError: must be string or pinned buffer, not bytearray
```

Comment: Why not read in larger chunks? And have you seen the `shutil` module? Last but not least, do use the `ironpython` tag as it might be relevant.

Comment: Just so you know, 0x32000 bytes is about 200 kB. Do you mean to write 32000 bytes instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I'm not using IronPython for this one.

Comment: You already knew to open the file for reading with `'rb'`, why did you open the file to write to in text mode instead? `'wb'` would solve the exception you have in one go.

Comment: Oh, misset that. Thanks. You can add it as an answer if you want to.

Comment: 32kb is 32,678 bytes, not 32,000 bytes.

Comment: `range(32,768)` is `[32, 33, 34, 35, ... 766, 767]`. You really don't want that comma.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to open the file in binary write mode (`wb`).

```
with open('file2.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(myArr)
```

Also, the way you are reading from the input file is pretty inefficient. `f.read()` allows you to read more than one byte at a time:

```
with open('file1.bin', 'rb') as f:
    myArr = bytearray(f.read(32678))
```

Will do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Open files with appropriate flags, then read from one in blocks of 1024 bytes and write to other, if less than 1024 bytes are remaining, copy byte-wise.

```
fin = open('file1.bin', 'rb')
fout = open('file2.bin', 'w+b')
while True:
  b=fin.read(1024)
  if b:
    n = fout.write(b)
  else:
    while True:
      b=fin.read(1)
      if b:
        n=fout.write(b)
      else:
        break
    break
```